# Creating a special text form field with a special view

Tags: android, flutter, textfield

I need a text field that, when the text is typed, will have a dim background color and a radius, and finally go to a new line by pressing enter, and the program exits as it should in the image I posted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgUGu.gif)

I tried to fix it with the container and I also gave a board, but the item that was used did not go to the new line with two spaces, and I did not manage to go to the new line with Inter.